# GridPane inside AnchorPane

Tags: javafx-8

I put a Gridpane inside on the AnchorPane , my Gridpane has a set of TextField , Label and Buttons and I want it to put in the Anchorpane but my GridPane is just sticking in the upper left of the AnchorPane i've set a setTopanchor etc... for the GridPane but it don't apply to the Anchorpane i want it to put in the center. here is the sample . Is there any missing for it just don't really apply in AnchorPane? tnx I'll be waiting for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question right and you want to center GridPane in AnchorPane, you can try something like this on each AnchorPane width or height changes (`anchorPane.widthProperty().addListener()`):

```
    double x = (anchorPane.getWidth() - GRID_SIZE) / 2;
    double y = (anchorPane.getHeight() - GRID_SIZE) / 2;

    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(grid, x);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(grid, y);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(grid, x);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(grid, y);
```

Basically, you need to calculate offset from each side and set an anchor.

Here is some demo code for StackPane and AncorPane: 
https://github.com/varren/JavaFX-Center-GridPane-in-other-Pane/tree/master/src/sample

But if you just want your grid to take full AnchorPane size, you can simply set

```
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(grid, .0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(grid, .0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(grid, .0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(grid, .0);
```

And there will be no need to listen for AnchorPane size changes.